# Convert sql server script syntax to oracle script syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, plsql

I have an application that is supposed to support two types of databases SQL SERVER and ORACLE. So we've been working forever on SQL Server and now we are making this support.

My idea was to create a tool to generate the scripts of creating the database using CMO then convert those scripts to PL/SQL Oracle scripts and run them on Oracle.

My questions are:

1. Is this syntax conversion possible in code?
2. I need a guideline to make this kind of syntax conversion.
3. Do you have a better suggestion to maintain two types of databases (i mean when making a change of one of them, we dont have to make it to the other. we need a tool to make that change.)?

Comment: Tools can never be better than humans.

Comment: Unlike SQL Server, Oracle makes a very clear distinction between the query language ("SQL") and the procedural language ("PL/SQL"). Mentioning PL/SQL **always** means you are writing some procedure or function in the Oracle world. Are you talking about automatically converting stored procedures from SQL Server T-SQL to Oracle PL/SQL? Or are you talking about converting SQL queries from SQL Server to Oracle? Converting queries in an automated fashion will be a *really* challenging task, but I don't think converting stored procedures will be feasible at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you write using standard sql it should be mostly portable. Eg use fetch instead of top, SET @a=.. instead of Select @a=.. Use Merge for updates  instead of join updates, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP instead of getdate() etc.

Comment: Thank, What am asking for is some kind of a table with all the changes that should be done. or a code sample that does the trick.